# Do we really need time limit on editing comments

Tags: support, feature-request, comment, editing, grace-period

I find time limit on editing comments annoying and doubt that it is needed at all. My problem is typos that I can't fix if I noticed them too late. If my comment is not answered I post the corrected version and then delete the old version. But if my comment is already answered, I can't do even this, and should see the ugly typo every time I visit the page.

Well, I can understand the answer like: removing time restriction requires too big changes in software and we will not do it, but I don't like false excuses.

Comment: Yes.  Edits to comments don't ping anyone.  So it is very possible that a spammer could post a comment, then invisibly return to it a month (or a year) later to insert spam.  The limit of 5 minutes is arbitrary, but it seems like the right order of magnitude in order to ensure that *someone* will see a spammy comment.

Comment: @XanderHenderson that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: @KReiser It already is an answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292247/ .

Comment: Editing comments would require to maintain revisions (otherwise it can lead to destruction of evidence required for mod work). Deleting and adding new comment isn't the same as editing because deleted comments are available to mods.

Comment: Solution: Check your comments for typos before hitting "Add comment".

Comment: Like all communal undertakings, the answer is "a bit of both". And we definitely don't subscribe to the kind of radical selfishness that says a user should be allowed to do whatever they want for their benefit without considering the detriment it could cause others.

Comment: Oh, and comments provide a really useful role, letting people have a bit of a discussion centralized under a post, not off on what may be multiple answers. You can petulantly choose not to use them if you wish, but I don't think people are going to stop using comments just because of their limited editing ability.

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC If "comments provide a really useful role" why not to improve them?

Comment: @kludg - I've noticed that two of your comments that I replied to have been deleted. I'm curious - was that you or a moderator that did so?

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC This is strange and not good. I did not delete comments.

Comment: Well, as is pointed out frequently, comments are transient, and might be removed at any time. If there are points from the comments that you think are important to your question, you should edit them back into the body of your question. That can work oddly when there is some "conversational" nature to the comments, as happened here. I've got my own theories, but if you are \*very\* concerned about why they were deleted, the best move is to contact the mods. .....

Comment: By me, the deleted ones weren't essential to the question of this post, and I'd  say they weren't worth the bother, but it is your call. (I'll leave my responses for now, in case you end up inserting your points into the main post, but if you decide not to, just ping me here and I'll probably delete them. They don't make much sense on their own. :-) )

Comment: I am not going to ask for explanation why my comments were deleted, I know there were nothing bad in them. I think my question is good, but it received negative reaction that I don't understand.

Comment: Comments deletion is a natural element of the toxic design of the site. It can be even done automatically.